# run several instances of svnsync to sync repostiory

Tags: sync, svn

I wonder is it possible to run several instances of `svnsyc` to speed up sync process? `svnsync` seems to be making lots of requests (at least one for each revision) and high ping substantially slows whole process. Running several svnsync instances concurrently may improve performance.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible:
as svnsync rebuilds revision after revision it can only work strictly linear and single threaded. To ensure this svnsync places a filelock into the repo so the second svnsync call will just end its service saying the repository is locked.